# Comprobar UPDATE correcto en MySql con PHP-PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Al lanzar una **INSERT MySql con PDO** tengo el mismo resultado ya se realice la actualización o no, siempre que no se produzcan errores, es decir que si por ejemplo la actualización no cumple las condiciones del `WHERE` no se producirá.

Ejemplo:

```
$sql = "UPDATE score SET bonus=1000 WHERE player='Anubis'";

$query = $con->prepare( $sql );

$res = ( $query )
    ? $query->execute()
    : NULL ;

var_dump( $res );
```

Lo anterior, ya sea que se encuentre o no el jugador de nombre *Anubis*, lanza el mismo resultado.

Hay una forma directa de comprobar que la **INSERT** fue bien sobre la variable **$res**, o la unica manera es ejecutando la actualización y luego lanzar un con **rowCount()**:

```
$sql = "UPDATE score SET bonus=1000 WHERE player='Anubis'";

$query = $con->prepare( $sql );
$query->execute();

$res = $query->rowCount();

var_dump( $res );
```

Entiendo que al hacerlo de esta manera, se están realizando dos llamadas a la BD en lugar de una sola, la primera para la actualización y la segunda para consultar el número de filas afectadas.

Comment: `$var = $query->execute();` retornará `TRUE` si se ejecutó correctamente. por ahí puede validar `if($var){...}`

Answer (score 2):

> Lo anterior, ya sea que se encuentre o no el jugador de nombre Anubis, lanza el mismo resultado.

Esto es debido a que `PDOStatement::execute` devuelve `true` si la sentencia está correctamente escrita y `false` si tiene algún error, de sintaxis, por ejemplo.

En caso de que quieras obtener la cantidad de filas afectadas por la sentencia (ya sea `INSERT`, `UPDATE` O `DELETE`) existe la posibilidad de utilizar `exec()`, que devuelve un entero con la cantidad de filas afectadas. En caso de no existir filas, entonces devuelve 0.

```
$update = "UPDATE score SET bonus = 1000 where player = "Anubis";

$filas = $db->exec($update);
// $filas = int(1) -- si existe el jugador Anubis
// $filas = int(0) -- si no existe el jugador Anubis
```

La desventaja del método `exec()` es que no se puede utilizar con `PDO::prepare()`.

Por otro lado, analizando los registros de *MySQL* pude comprobar que `PDO::rowCount` no realiza una nueva consulta a la base de datos.

Ejemplo utilizando `exec()`:

```
SET timestamp=1490834071;
update tabla set nombre = 'Cuchufleto' where id = 2;
User@Host: root[db] @ localhost [::1]
Thread_id: 13  Schema: angulara  QC_hit: No
Query_time: 0.000003  Lock_time: 0.000000  Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
Rows_affected: 0
```

Ejemplo utilizando `execute()` y luego `rowCount()`:

```
SET timestamp=1490834148;
update tabla set nombre = 'Cuchufletito' where id = 2;
User@Host: root[db] @ localhost [::1]
Thread_id: 14  Schema: angulara  QC_hit: No
Query_time: 0.000004  Lock_time: 0.000000  Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
Rows_affected: 0
SET timestamp=1490834148;
```

Answer (score 0):

La validación dependerá de si en tu conexión has establecido el atributo: **[`PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`](http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.setattribute.php)** o no.

### A. Si al conectar has establecido dicho atributo

Si al conectar has hecho algo parecido a esto:

```
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Significa que si algo falla se levantará una excepción. En ese caso la validación se hará dentro de un bloque `try/catch` :

```
try 
{
  $query->execute(...);
  echo 'Consulta exitosa';

} catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

### B. Si el modo error no está activado

El método **[`execute()`](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.execute.php)** devuelve `TRUE` en caso de éxito o `FALSE` en caso de error.

Por tanto, para validar:

```
if ($query->execute(...)) {
   echo 'Consulta exitosa';

} else {
   echo 'Un error ha ocurrido';

}
```